# How to convert date from string datetype in Vue and Pug?

Tags: vue.js, pug

I have this pug file which I want to compare the system date with the date in the object using VueJs.

This is what I have. I have print the system date using this line `div #{new Date()}` which output `Mon Oct 18 2021 10:46:39 GMT+0800 (Malaysia Time)`

I have also print the date using this vue syntax `div {{event.details.meta.date}}` which output `2021-10-17`

The question is how do I convert this date from string to datatype and then compare it to the system date?

I tried with `div #{new Date("event.details.meta.date")}` but the output is `Invalid date`

I tried `div(v-if="isEventActive(event.details.meta.date)")`

and

```
computed: {
  isEventActive(_eventDate) {
    var eventDate = new Date(_eventDate);
    return new Date() < eventDate;
  }, 
}
```

But it says `isEventActive is not a function`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vue computed properties don't accept parameters.  It's the return value of the function that is visible in your template.

To solve your issue, you can either:

1. move your `isEventActive` function into the `methods` section, or
2. use a computed property and return a function.

The first approach looks like this:

```js
methods: {
    isEventActive(_eventDate) {
        var eventDate = new Date(_eventDate);
        return new Date() < eventDate;
    }, 
}
```

If this doesn't work (i.e., the page doesn't properly update on changes to `eventDate`) then try this:

```js
computed: {
    isEventActive() {
        return function(_eventDate) {
            var eventDate = new Date(_eventDate);
            return new Date() < eventDate;  
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`div #{new Date("event.details.meta.date")}` outputs `Invalid date` because the string `"event.details.meta.date"` is not a valid value for the [`Date()` constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/Date).

`div #{new Date(event.details.meta.date)}` on the other hand should output something like `Mon Oct 17 2021 08:00:00 GMT+0800 (Malaysia Time)` because you are passing the value of `event.details.meta.date`, which apparently is `'2021-10-17'`, to the `Date()` constructor.

---

`div(v-if="isEventActive(event.details.meta.date)")` outputs `<div v-if="isEventActive(event.details.meta.date)"></div>`.

You probably want this instead: `<div v-if="isEventActive('2021-10-17')"></div>`. Then in your `isEventActive` method the value of the `_eventDate` parameter would be `'2021-10-17'`. (Probably; I'm not familiar with Vue.)

So you could try this:

```html
// Input (Vue):
div(v-if=`isEventActive('${event.details.meta.date}')`)

// Output (HTML):
<div v-if="isEventActive('2021-10-17')"></div>
```

The same but without a [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals):

```html
// Input (Vue):
div(v-if="isEventActive('" + event.details.meta.date + "')")

// Output (HTML):
<div v-if="isEventActive('2021-10-17')"></div>
```

Comment: `div #{new Date(event.details.meta.date)}` doesn't work.

Comment: `div(v-if=`isEventActive('${event.details.meta.date}')`)` also doesn't work